# Cant get the value to pass from my dictionary

Tags: c#

```
        Dictionary<string, double> state = new Dictionary<string, double>(50);

        state.Add("Alabama", 0.0570);
        state.Add("Alaska", 0.1167);
        state.Add("Arizona", 0.0592);
        state.Add("Arkansas", 0.0835);
        state.Add("California", 0.0739);
        state.Add("Colorado", 0.0272);
        state.Add("Connecticut", 0.06540);
        state.Add("Delaware", 0.0825);
        state.Add("Florida", 0.0503);
        state.Add("Georgia", 0.0562);
        state.Add("Hawaii", 0.0985);
        state.Add("Idaho", 0.0736);
        state.Add("Illinois", 0.0562);
        state.Add("Indiana", 0.0648);
        state.Add("Iowa", 0.0591);
        state.Add("Kansas", 0.0654);
        state.Add("Kentucky", 0.0734);
        state.Add("Louisiana", 0.0685);
        state.Add("Maine", 0.0770);
        state.Add("Maryland", 0.0559);
        state.Add("Massachusetts", 0.0630);
        state.Add("Michigan", 0.0672);
        state.Add("Minnesota", 0.0802);
        state.Add("Mississippi", 0.0740);
        state.Add("Missouri", 0.0517);
        state.Add("Montana", 0.0708);
        state.Add("Nebraska", 0.0610);
        state.Add("Nevada", 0.0612);
        state.Add("New Hampshire", 0.0387);
        state.Add("New Jersey", 0.0661);
        state.Add("New Mexico", 0.0826);
        state.Add("New York", 0.0676);
        state.Add("North Carolina", 0.0726);
        state.Add("North Dakota", 0.0711);
        state.Add("Ohio", 0.0609);
        state.Add("Oklahoma", 0.0621);
        state.Add("Oregon", 0.0576);
        state.Add("Pennsylvania", 0.0617);
        state.Add("Rhode Island", 0.0640);
        state.Add("South Carolina", 0.0619);
        state.Add("South Dakota", 0.0423);
        state.Add("Tennessee", 0.0539);
        state.Add("Texas", 0.0438);
        state.Add("Utah", 0.0728);
        state.Add("Vermont", 0.1060);
        state.Add("Virginia", 0.0563);
        state.Add("Washington", 0.0648);
        state.Add("West Virginia", 0.0834);
        state.Add("Wisconsin", 0.0693);
        state.Add("Wyoming", 0.0778);


        string stateKey = textBox1.Text.Trim().ToUpper();

        if (state.ContainsKey(stateKey))
        {
            StateTax = state[stateKey];
        }
        else
        {
            string messageBoxText = "Missing rate for state " + stateKey;
            MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText);
            return;
        }
```

So this is what i have so far, i cant get StateTax To take the value of one of my dictionary Values.This usually doesn't take me that long but my brain is just freezing lately on thinking. Whats the best way to write this?

Comment: Thanks Everyone for helping me out on this, i never knew their was such a good site out there for programmers it definitely helps when i have a stupid brain freeze like this one hahah i got it fixed thanks to everyone, i picked what i thought was a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are upper casing:

```
string stateKey = textBox1.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
```

but dictionary keys are in proper caps:

```
"Wyoming"
```

Either place in dictionary as all lower or upper case, and do the same to your entered value, OR make entered text first caps (the former is preferable)

**UPDATE**: or even better! use Anthony's or Ed's idea of a case insensitive dictionary!

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary stores the keys like "Abc", but you are attempting to retrieve the value using the key "ABC". To fix your specific dilemna, specify a comparer that ignores case completely.

```
var stateTaxTable = new Dictionary<string, decimal>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Also notice I'm making the value a `decimal` as a suggestion. It is more fitting of storing a value to be used in a financial calculation. You would store it in the dictionary using the `M` suffix on the value. Example:

```
stateTaxTable.Add("Some State", 0.075M);
```

If you are multiplying a price by this value, you'd want the price to be a `decimal`, as well. Again, these are *suggestions*, but it's good to get in the habit of using the proper type for financial data.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `ToUpper` on your key, but you didn't add the keys to the dictionary in all caps:

```
string stateKey = textBox1.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
```

`"ALABAMA" != "Alabama"`, so you will need to either:

1. Call `ToUpper()` or `ToLower()` on your user input and enter your keys accordingly, or
2. Use a case insensitive compare  <-- Better option

The `Dictionary<K,V>` class will take an `IEqualityComparer<T>` in one of its constructors.  Use it to define how to compare key values.

```
var caseInsensitiveDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>(
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

The [StringComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx) class implements the `IEqualityComparer` interface.

Comment: I might have been typing fast but wasn't thinking enough!!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Hehe, well, after 3174 good responses I think you can be given some slack for your minor lapse.

Answer (score 0):

The `.ToUpper()` is your problem.

Whatever's in the textbox is being normalized to uppercase, but the keys are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Your are converting the state input to upper case.  You will never find the entry in the dictionary.

Either (1) change code to use upper case state names or (2) remove the ToUpper and create the dictionary with a case insensitive comparer.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use

```
String stateKey =
               CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(textbox1.Text);
```